# How to walk around the folders of my solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

i have 7 projects in one solution on asp.net mvc. I seperate the model classes, the controllers, the cshtml files, the view models etc. on other projects. In each project i seperate the the classes etc. on other folders. For example in my Application.Viewmodel project, there are 4 folders, each of them has its own viewmodels. Each project has its own namespace of course. Now i have to walk around the folders by reflection, to take the viewmodel names of each folder. I can retrieve the whole viewmodel names with the code below. But its important to know which viewmodel stays in which folder to me. I want to take the viewmodel names one by one from each folder. How can i do that?

```
string @namespace = "Application.Viewmodel";

List<String> viewModels = new List<string>();
List<Type> returnVal = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                                .GetAssemblies()
                                .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
                                .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < returnVal.Count; i++)
{
     viewModels.Add(returnVal[i].Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When your code is compiled, the physical location of the original files isn't kept. An assembly is just a bundle of type definitions. You can get that from the PDB file, but not really the same thing.

**If you need to organize your classes, you should do it using namespaces**. Do something like `MyProject.ViewModels.FolderA` and `MyProject.ViewModels.FolderB`.

Here's a very simplistic example that assumes the last segment of the namespace is the unique part:

```
var typesGroupedByNamespace = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => t.IsClass && t.Namespace.StartsWith(@namespace))
    .GroupBy(t => t.Namespace.Substring(t.Namespace.LastIndexOf(".") + 1));
```

Comment: when i do that, can i use a foreach loop for the namespaces? I dont want to hard coding.

Comment: @TamerMemili I am not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @TamerMemili the code example I provided will return a `IGrouping<string, Type>` where the key value is the last segment of the namespace (i.e. "FolderA"). You can loop over an IGrouping to get each group's key and its members.

Comment: yes, thats what i am asking, thank you for your help!

Comment: @TamerMemili excellent. If you feel like your question has been completely answered, please click the check-mark under the voting buttons next to the answer to accept it.

Comment: tomorrow i will try it on my code, if it works, i will do that, dont worry :)